# lightning/empApi does not handle new record creation

Tags: lightning-web-components, streaming-api

Let's say i have custom object LOT__c in my org and LWC from 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation

then I set channel name to /data/LOT__c__ChangeEvent and subscribe channel.
But when I create new lot nothing's happened with channel. (LOT is included into Change Data Capture
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not have `__c` for change events subscription - [Refer to this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_channels.htm)

> #### Custom Object
>
> `/data/<Custom_Object_Name>__ChangeEvent`
>
> For example, the channel to subscribe to change events for Employee__c
>   custom object records is:
>
> `/data/Employee__ChangeEvent`

#### In your case it should be `/data/LOT__ChangeEvent`